# Split the line including all words and special characters

Tags: shell, tcl

Hi I have string `abc_99\\/de_f/gij` I want a list as:

```
abc_99  \\/  de_f  /  gij
```

How do I need to do tcl script

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression that will match either a sequence of word characters, or a sequence of non-word characters:

```
set s {abc_99\\/de_f/gij}
regexp -all -inline {\w+|\W+} $s
```

This gives: `abc_99 {\\/} de_f / gij`